# Redirect Subdomain to root Domain with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having a subdomain:

```
http://admin.domain.nl
```

But when i'm going to this site it should redirect me to my DirectAdmin site which is:

```
http://domain.nl:2222/
```

How to do this in the .htaccess file?

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:admin\.)?domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.nl:2222/ [L,R]
```

but it's somehow not working and i'm getting a not found error from T-Online.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://domain.nl:2222/ [L,R]
```

Comment: It's giving me the same :(

Comment: So when you enter `http://admin.domain.nl` it doesn't change this URL in browser?

Comment: it does change the url, but not to the desired one. IT changes to: http://navigationshilfe1.t-online.de/dnserror?url=http://admin.domain.nl/

Comment: It does, hmmm i think i have the problem. The subdomain isn't found somehow :s

Comment: Ah domain itself doesn't exist :P

Comment: Hmmm it did exist but somehow i'm not allowed or something to call it admin, so i've made it administrator instead :) Thanks this is the solution :D